# TypeScript Map to Java Map

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular2-template

I want to call java Api  from my angular 2 app.I used typescript Map to send request in java app.
 My RestEndpoint in java is like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = Constants.PATH_BASE + "/sync/list")
public ResponseEntity<?>configureQueueList(@RequestBody Map<String,Integer> map){
   //code here 
    }
```

I got this error when i try to use typescript map:

> JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@f6b068c; line: 1, column: 1]

In postman i use this as  raw body and it works

> ```
> {
>  "key1":"value1",
>  "key2":"value2",
>  .....
>  .....
> }
> ```

**Edit 2:**
Type Script Endpoint

```
postMap(value:Map<string,number>){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            return this.http.post(this.url, value, options)
            .map(success => success.status)
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Please also provide your typescript end-point, since there seems to be the problem.

Comment: i just edit the question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please ensure, that your actual request body, starts with `{` tag, not: `[`. As you have written, in Postman you wrap your request with `{ }`, whereas error message:

> > [JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of **START_ARRAY** **token**;...
>
> ...Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@f6b068c; **line: 1, column:
>   1**]

suggests, that your actual request is wrapped with `[ ]` tags

**EDIT** (to answer your first comment):
Translate your `Map` into `Object`. For example you can achieve it with this function:

```
function mapToObj(strMap) {
        let obj = Object.create(null);
        for (let [k,v] of strMap) {
            obj[k] = v; //look out! Key must be a string!
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Then provide the result of your transformation into the `http.post` line

**Edit 2** The above answer will work if you are using es6, if you are using es5 u can try using a dictionary like this

```
let map:{ [name: string]: number }={};
map["key1"]=value1;
map["key2"]=value2;
```

Comment: Angular 2 converts in a json string starts with [  how i can change to start with {

Comment: I extended my answer, please take a look:)